# Postgres: turn off formating for xml export?

Tags: postgresql, serialization

I want to export some table to xml file:

```sql
\o output.xml
SELECT table_to_xml('modified_records', TRUE, TRUE, '');
```

However, I'm struggling with psql formatting. The best I managed to get is:

```sql
\t on
\x on
\pset format unaligned
\o modified_records.xml
SELECT table_to_xml('modified_records', TRUE, TRUE, '');
\o
```

Which results in

```
table_to_xml|<modified_records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tag1>val1</tag1>
  <tag2>val2</tag2>
</modified_records>

<modified_records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tag1>val1</tag1>
  <tag2>val2</tag2>
</modified_records>

<modified_records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tag1>val1</tag1>
  <tag2>val2</tag2>
</modified_records>
```

So I still have to remove `table_to_xml|`. Which is not hard:

```sh
cat modified_records.xml | sed '1s/^table_to_xml|//' 

# or even in psql:
\o | sed '1s/^table_to_xml|//' > modified_records.xml
```

but feels like fighting with Postgres.

Is there a way to dump just the value?

(there are plenty of options for `\pset`, but I can't find its docs)

Comment: Remove the `\x on` (or use `\x off`)

Comment: You'll find the `\pset` docs at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html.

Comment: @dezso: right it is there closer to the bottom. I saw that page actually, but didn't scrolled all the way to the bottom.

Comment: `psql -qAt` is what you usually want

Answer (score 3):

The psql command \? shows the option to turn off expanded formatting:

```
Formatting:
...
  \x [on|off|auto]       toggle expanded output (currently off)
```

Typically it will show table data in one record per line if its "off" or else each field in its own line when switched on, e.g.:

```
postgres=# \x off
Expanded display is off.
postgres=# \l
                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_IN   | en_IN |
```

When its switched on:

```
postgres=# \x on
Expanded display is on.
postgres=# \l
List of databases
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----+----------------------
Name              | postgres
Owner             | postgres
Encoding          | UTF8
Collate           | en_IN
Ctype             | en_IN
Access privileges |
-[ RECORD 2 ]-----+----------------------
```

With xml output, since everything is in one stream, it shows the record label before printing out the xml.
The difference between /x on and /x off is as follows:

```
/x on

table_to_xml|<pg_attribute xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <attrelid>1255</attrelid>
  <attname>proname</attname>
  <atttypid>19</atttypid>
  <attstattarget>-1</attstattarget>
```

With `/x off` the output is:

```
/x off
<pg_attribute xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <attrelid>1255</attrelid>
  <attname>proname</attname>
  <atttypid>19</atttypid>
  <attstattarget>-1</attstattarget>
```

So before writing to the file you should change the commands issued as follows:

```
\t on
\x off
\pset format unaligned
```